# LibreOffice installed by default is not a stable version

Tags: libreoffice

Why does Ubuntu come pre-installed with LibreOffice version (4.0.2.2) not a stable version (4.0.2)? I suspected that I have seen via [distrowatch.com/ubuntu](http://distrowatch.com/ubuntu) in packages list that using stable version. I prefer to use a stable version like (4.0.2) than release candidate (4.0.2.2). I have seen in Help => About LibreOffice. Can Ubuntu change it from RC2 version to stable version 4.0.2?

I also like update to the later stable version with an added PPA for LibreOffice, if there is a really stable release.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using.  Are you using a PPA to install libreoffice - if so which one?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.04 Raring-Ringtail. Yes, I have added PPA LibreOffice package since Raring released. I use LibreOffice 4.0.4.2 now.

Comment: please edit your question with any replies - you also havent answered my PPA query - which PPA?.  Stock 13.04 is using 4.0.2 as per http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=raring&searchon=names&keywords=libreoffice

Comment: I just noticed this issue.. mine is 4.0.2.2 as well.

Comment: I can also confirm that on a clean 13.04 install, the LO version is `Version 4.0.2.2 (Build ID: 400m0(Build:2))`.

Comment: What is the same version between RC2 and stable version? I think they're different version in features, unstable, etc parable like incompletely cooked in RC2 version. Than LibreOffice stable version 4.0.2 is parable like completely cooked than RC2 version.

Answer (score 2):

The stable version is the same as RC2, as stated in LibreOffice's [release notes](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/release-notes/). That page refers to the version 4.0.4 but I remember that they have done this before (like with the version 3.6.6 mentioned on that page). LibreOffice's [Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-0) also states that the minor releases are often identical to their RC2 versions.

However, I'm not sure why the repositories have not been updated to the final release of 4.0.4, though the [list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice) of LO's version in different versions of Ubuntu suggests that Raring's current version won't be updated unless a security fix is released later for the 4.0.x series. Meanwhile, you can use the `ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0` [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-0) to get the 4.0.4 version.